# Masonry "stamp"-method not surrounding

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

Masonry 3 has been added a method "stamp" which is great to fix a certain element in place. However, it doesn't seem to work properly / as I would've expected it to work.

Take this example from David DeSandro himself:

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wKpjs

All is well. Now we take the fixed element down by 200px so there is enough space **above** the fixed element:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eILHG

As you can see, no elements are above the stamped element. Is there anything we can do about it or is it just the way it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way Masonry is written, when it does the stamp event it assigns a Y value to the column based on the the max value between that current column Y value and the offset of the stamp, so in this case because you have `position: absolute`, it assigns the column Y value of that column as the bottom of the stamp block, so nothing is placed in the column besides the stamp.  Since `manageStamps` is the first thing called when `layout` is triggered, a work around would be to position the stamps as they come into the column range (and any that don't at the end) by rewriting a bit of Masonry to check each time it goes to place an item, but that operation would be more costly as the # of stamps/blocks goes up.

**Edit**: As an aside, Packery fixes this, and it's also a project by the same guy (though has a license cost).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I only ever have one item stamped, so I think it'd work, but I don't fully get how to rework it atm. Need to look at it later...

Comment: As a side note, Packery fixes this.